# Structure application by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, modular-design

I am going to build an application as it is not too much rich otherwise I can use angularjs for that purpose. I wanted to organize my JS code into proper modular programming approach.

E.g

```
   var SignUpModule = {
     elem: $('#id'), // unable to access jquery object here
     init: function (jQuery) {
       alert(jQuery('.row').html());
    }
};

 var application = {
modules: [],
addModule: function (module) {
    this.modules.push(module);
},
run: function (jQuery) {
    _.each(this.modules, function (module) {

        //Iterate each module and run init function
        module.init(jQuery);
    });


    }
  }


jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    application.addModule(SignUpModule);//add module to execute in application

    application.run(jQuery);//Bootstrap application

});
```

Please now look at it I have updated my question with actual code

Comment: jQuery object (either `jQuery` or `$`) is global, so you don't really have to put it anywhere. What you wrote will probably work just fine. I don't really understand your problem.

Comment: to access jquery insie module, in this way i need to pass jquery object to init method

    var module = {
        elem: $('#id'), // unable to access jquery object here
        init: function (jquery){ // yes getting here
       }   
    }

I hope I able to explain my problem?

Comment: Please edit your original question and add some code which will show us where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest mistake you've done is using anonymous first parameter of an anonymous function taken by `$.each` method. The first argument is just index, and the second argument is an element you were looking for. Below you can find working code.

And no, you don't need to pass `jQuery` object everywhere. It's global. It already **is everywhere**. You can see it in the code below.

```js
var SignUpModule = {
  elem: $('.row'), //jQuery works fine here
  init: function () {
    alert(this.elem.html());
  }
};

var application = {
  modules: [],
  addModule: function (module) {
    this.modules.push(module);
  },
  run: function () {
    $.each(this.modules, function (index, module) { //this function takes 2 parameters
      //Iterate each module and run init function
      module.init();
    });
  }
}

//document.ready
$(function () {
    application.addModule(SignUpModule);//add module to execute in application
    application.run();//Bootstrap application
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">alert <b>me!</b></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you have solved my problem and also I have used underscorejs but thanks for the help :)

Comment: I thought it was underscore, but why mix it if jQuery has it ;)

Comment: underscore _.each is more power I think it has good browser compatibility

Comment: Look at this benchmark: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-underscore-each-vs-for-loops/4 jQuery is faster then underscore, but not as fast as native for loop.